# Run PPSX or PPT using Sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am trying to develop an application for iPad using Sencha touch which needs to run a local PPT or PPSX file on a  button click and return to main application after finishing the presentation .I am not sure whether this is possible.Please share your thoughts..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  I understand your problem;

With sencha-touch, code runs on browser, so you could not access local files of users file system except he choose files with a file chooser(but in that case you must upload the file to server).

If you want to open a file without closing your app, you may open file in a new window.

I hope, this gives you some idea.